# Go jogging is a verb or noun?

Tags: phrase-meaning

go jogging is a  verb or a  noun ? I wanted to say " I was not accustomed to go jogging " but I do not know  if go jogging would be right or going jogging would be true

Comment: Since you need a ***noun*** (for a *thing* you're not accustomed to), you need the ***gerund*** form - *I was not accustomed to **going** jogging*, for example (but you could just discard the auxiliary ***going***, and let ***jogging*** be the gerund noun).

Answer (score 1):

The *Oxford English Dictionary* has a useful category for this word — a **verbal noun**. In other words, it is a noun designating the action of the verb ***jog***. Any word of this same form — ***singing***, ***flying***, ***sobbing*** — works in the same way (although they may not always work with the word ***go***). Another interpretation is that it is a present participle that functions as a noun. But, whatever you call it, it has some of the attributes of the verb, but functions as a noun.

- I like to go jogging.
- I like going jogging.
- I was not accustomed to going jogging.
- I was not accustomed to jogging.
- Jogging is not my favourite activity.